# Testing Gingerbread Cordova in Browser

Tags: android, css, cordova, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm having trouble emulating Android Gingerbread for my Cordova app using my browser. You see, I released an app for Gingerbread+ using Cordova to GooglePlay. After a bit, I was getting a lot of reviews saying that it didn't work. I checked one of the user's devices and noticed they were using Gingerbread, so I emulated it using Android Studio.

When testing on an actual simulator, it is obvious that the CSS is not being applied properly in this old browser window. But I don't want to test using the emulator until I am just about ready to export again. Building takes at least a minute on there, and I have no idea what CSS rules are valid, and which are not on Gingerbread. I had to release a new version of my app that is for version 19 (4.4)+. But I would like to release a new version that allows users with a lower API level to still use the app.

So I need to do a lot of testing to get a feel for what I can and cannot do. I tried to use Ripple, which said I was using Android version 2.x.x, but the app works properly when it shouldn't.

Does anyone know how I can actually use the same browser as Gingerbread uses, or at least simulate it? It's much faster to just press Apple+R to refresh the page than going through the Android Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Use genymotion, is an android virtual machine that runs faster than the android simulator:

https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

They have some 2.3.7 devices to test.

And you can take a look into http://caniuse.com/ to see some supported features by browser version